# Google Sheets Hide Columns/rows based on Checkboxes in another tab on the same Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im new to google scripting and was hoping someone could help me out. I have looked at many videos online to try and complete the task I have.

Scenario: TO be able to manage orderable items from a single Tab using check boxes in googlesheets. I have a Control sheet that has the sellable items and along side them a checkbox that indicats (True) Item available, (FALSE) Item unavailable.

In another tab in the same sheet there are the exact same items list horizontally and then lower down vertically. What I would like to have help with is a script that would run onEdit, that when an item in teh control tab is checked/uncheck, the relevant item in both the rows and the columns are hidden/revealed.

Link to Googlesheet I am referencing above.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15xwomFkO0FNtPCZU9BvTWZp5YUozPfon7E2svouM7-w/edit?usp=sharing

I hope someone can help me solve this as its been baffling me for a very long time.

TIA

Comment: Are you trying to hide just the cells that contain those specific values(as if they are column/row names) or should it also affect adjacent cells, for example: ```Total Orders``` too? Also, would you be OK with using formulas if it's possible? If possible please share an example of the expected output when one of the values is set to "TRUE".

Answer (score 0):

I used a installable onEdit trigger:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let items = { pA: [] };
    let vs = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, 2).getValues();
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
    vs.forEach((r, i) => {
      if (r[0] == true) {
        items.pA.push(r[1]);
      }
    })
    let oA = items.pA.map(p => p);
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
    let osh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    osh.getRange(6, 3, 2, osh.getLastColumn() - 2).clearContent().removeCheckboxes();
    if (items.pA.length) {
      osh.getRange(6, 3, 1, items.pA.length).setValues([items.pA]);
      osh.getRange(7, 3, 1, items.pA.length).insertCheckboxes();
    }
    let oB = items.pA.map(pa => [pa]);
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oB));
    if(osh.getLastRow() > 10) {
      osh.getRange(11, 1, osh.getLastRow() - 10).clearContent();
    }
    osh.getRange(11, 1, oB.length).setValues(oB);
  }
}
```

You will have to change the sheet names

[image]